# Why does c++ && operator need priority

Tags: c++

```
test1() && test2() != test3();
```

In this example despite of precedence of `!=` heigher than `&&` the order of evaluation is always: if `test1()` then `test2 != test3()`.

Why does c++ && operator need priority? Could you provide an example where operator show its pryority but not an evaluation?

Comment: That's known as short-circuit Boolean evaluation.

Comment: Are you asking why the `&&` operator has short-circuiting behavior?

Comment: you want this behaviour: `if (a != null && a->foo() == 1)`

Comment: I ask about example where operator `&&` uses its priority in expression but not a short-circuit behaviour

Comment: @Igor I don't know what distinction you're trying to make.  The fact the the left-hand side of an `&&` operator is evaluated first and the right-hand side is evaluated only if the left-hand side was `true` _is_ short-circuiting.  There is no distinct concept of priority.

Comment: @Igor The precedence defines how the sub-expressions will be grouped, not when they will be evaluated.

Comment: @MilesBudnek If it is used only for short-circuiting then why does it have priority?

Comment: @Igor I really don't know what you mean by priority.  For short-circuiting to work the entire left-hand side must be evaluated before any of the right-hand side.  That's all that's going on here.  The left-hand expression `test1()` is evaluated, and if it's `false` no part of the right-hand expression `test2() != test3()` gets evaluated.  As others have said, operator precedence only defines how arguments are grouped, not the order in which they're evaluated.

Comment: @Igor It needs a notion of precedence (priority) to define how the expression will be evaluated. For example, `&&` has priority over `||`, so `a||b&&c` will be evaluated as `a||(b&&c)`. However, `==` has priority over `&&`, so `a==b&&c` will be evaluated as `(a==b)&&c`. Thus, the notion of precedence is still very important, regardless of the order of evaluation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question verbiage is misleading, and it took a me a while to understand what OP is asking about. When rules of precedence applied to this statement, and `!=` having higher precedence than `&&`, it means that

```
test1() && test2() != test3();
```

Is sematically equivalent to

```
test1() && (test2() != test3());
```

Rather than

```
(test1() && (test2()) != test3();
```

However, having short-circuit rules in place, compiler will first execute `test1()`, and when found false, will not execute `test2()` or `test3()`. This doesn't mean that the rules of precedence are not followed.

Answer (score 2):

The higher precedence of != means that

```
test1() && test2() != test3()
```

is equivalent tomain top operation of expression

```
test1() && (test2() != test3())
```

rather than

```
(test1() && test2()) != test3()
```

So, this is an expression of form `subexpr1 && subexpr2`. Where the != operation is in the second subexpression. The logical AND operation is specified so that left hand operand is executed first, and second operator is executed second (or not at all if left result is false).

Comment: It is funny how very similar our answers are :), especially in the beginning.

Comment: @SergeyA wow :D Is this where you call *Jinx!* ?